# NodeJS + Android SSL Authentication

Tags: android, node.js

I have no idea how to debug this, been at this for a while now, any pointers would be appreciated.

I am trying out ssl/tls authentication between an Android app and a Nodejs server. I am running into this error message when I run the android app:

```
10-31 23:33:58.260: D/ExampleActivity(26199): Response code: 401
10-31 23:34:05.901: W/DefaultRequestDirector(26199): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
```

**Note** that I have commented out the client authentication parts, and just trying to get basic SSL authentication working. Even that gives me the same warning/error.

### NodeJs - Server.js

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('certs/server_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/server.pem'),
   // ca: [fs.readFileSync('certs/client.pem')],
    passphrase: '33333',
   // requestCert: true,
   // rejectUnauthorized: false
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    if (req.client.authorized) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end('{"status":"approved"}');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(401, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end('{"status":"denied"}');
    }
}).listen(8000);
```

### Android

```
public class SecureHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
    private String ks = "11111";
    private String ts = "22222";
    private Context context;

    public SecureHttpClient(final Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory factory = newSslSocketFactory();
        factory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        registry.register(new Scheme("https", factory, 443));
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        return new SingleClientConnManager(httpParams, registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            InputStream inKey= context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client);
            InputStream inTrust = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.clienttruststore);
            try {
                keyStore.load(inKey, ks.toCharArray());
                trustStore.load(inTrust, ts.toCharArray());
            } finally {
                inKey.close();
                inTrust.close();
            }
            return new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

// MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setStrictMode();

        final HttpClient client = new SecureHttpClient(this);

        // Provide ip or address to where your test server is runnning
        final HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://192.168.0.105:8000/");

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("ExampleActivity", "Response code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    @TargetApi(9) 
    private void setStrictMode() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems your server is running on port 8000 and your Android app only register the `SSLSocketFactory` for 443, so it is essentially trying to speak HTTP to an HTTPS server. Either use port 443 for the server, or register for 8000 in the `SchemeRegistry`.

Comment: Yes, I tested it out with curl, and using chrome. It gives me a proper response.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the client key+certificate bks file with a pkcs12 seems to fix the issue. I have no idea why however.

Comment: Check the contents of both files and make sure CA (or server, if self-signed) are imported as trusted entries.

Comment: Okay, so it fixes the issue if I do a mutual authentication. However, if I remove the client authentication, it complains again. Yes, I made sure they are being imported as trusted sources.